# What data structure should be used to represent a street network?

Tags: java, data-structures, data-modeling

I'm trying to think of a way to represent a street network in my program, just a simple one like this:
A main street A with a couple of intersections, say a, b, c, d.
Another street B parallel with A. So something looks like this:

```
----|a|---|b|----|c|-------------------
                    Street A
----|a|---|b|-----------------|d|------
    | |   | |                 | |
    | |   | |                 | |
----|a|---|b|-----------------| |------
                Street B
------------------------------|d|------
```

I was thinking maybe I could just create a `Street` class to represent the two main streets and each will have two lists of intersections: Left and Right.
But I can tell this will get messy real quick as I add more streets to the network.

So suggestion would be much appreciated!
(Might be irrelevant, but I'm using Java)

**Edit 1:** Additionally, for this project, the directions of traffic allowed are very important - i.e., the data structure should be able to tell whether a street is one-way as well as one-way in which direction. I should be able to access this info easily from the data structure.

Comment: A directed graph with weights?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Street class and an Intersection class.  The Intersection class will function as a node and have references to the streets that are connected to it.  That's most-likely the most flexible design you could go with.  Maybe add (x,y) coordinates for the Street end points as-well.

Answer (score 0):

A system of streets can fit very nicely into a `GraphDB`. Streets being represented by edges and intersections as nodes. Perhaps something like `Neo4j` would suit your needs. There are other on memory alternatives if you don't need something so heavy weight.

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, if I consider the intersections as nodes, it would be hard to have the info about direction of traffic on these nodes unless I have to incorporate that data into the "Node" class.

Comment: @abcXYZ Intersections don't have traffic directions, streets do. Intersections simply serve as attachments for other streets.

Comment: Exactly, in a Directed Graph the edges will contain information about which way the traffic is travelling. You would have an edge going in both directions on a 2 way street, or just one for a 1 way street.